# Merging sorted n lists

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How the problem of sorting a very huge list is tackled?

I suppose we divide the list and have them process in each CPU and produce small sorted lists.

But how can we combine and produce a final sorted list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge mutiple sorted lists using [priority queu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)e (based on binary heap).

Fill queue with pairs `(current element of list or its index; list id)`.

```
At every step: 
   extract pair with min element from queue
   add value to result
   get the next element of the same list (if possible)
   insert new pair into queue again
```

How huge is your list relative to available memory?
For useful clues start from [wiki external sorting page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! For practical purpose, the list is larger than amount of main memory.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach should be create a min-heap of size (n) where n is the number of partitioned sorted  list from huge list.
Each node of binary heap should be represented like index/sorted_list_number and value.
The top node of min heap will point the min value of huge list and index will point from which sorted list its coming, Now pop top from min heap add its value in huge list and add new value from popped index list in to heap and heapify again. 
Repeat till node finish , also take care for heapsize when one/more of the list are getting empty in process.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is that your list is larger than memory, I would say external sort is the solution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

1. Say we have N blocks of main memory, we can load N-1 blocks of two list. Use the remaining one block as an output buffer
2. Merge two list by performing usual merging through comparing the front element. Output the result to the output buffer.
3. When the buffer is full, write the output back to secondary memory.
4. Repeat the steps until all the lists are merged.